# Use a custom sound file for cordova-plugin-dialogs

Tags: ios, cordova, audio

I am using the https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-dialogs plugin in my cordova application to play a beep sound. The application is for iOS. I need to replace the sound file and use my own. Unfortunately I am not sure where to place my wav file. The documentation does not mention anything for iOS. I found somewhere that I have to copy a beep.wav file to the www root folder. I did that and it doesn't take the new file. I am not sure what else needs to be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fork the plugin and replace the `beep.wav` file that is inside the `CDVNotification.bundle` with your own `beep.wav` and then use your fork instead of the original plugin

Comment: Yup. I found the same info after looking through the source. Still going to mark your response as the answer. Thanks